# Saving contact form data in a file by pressing a submit button doesn't seem to work

Tags: php, html

I made a contact form with a submit button. I want all the information saved which got typed into the contact form. Somehow the submit button does nothing.

In the past it seemed to work but as a php/html newbie I just cant seem to find the problem

**HTML**

```
        <form method="post">
            <div class="contact-form" action="contact-form.php" method="post">
                <div class="contentLeft">
                    <h4>Ihre Daten</h4>
                    <br>
                    <h3>Vorname</h3>
                    <input class="inputText" type="text" name="firstName" required="required">
                    <br>
                    <h3>Nachname</h3>
                    <input class="inputText" type="text" name="lastName" required="required">
                    <br>
                    <h3>E-Mail</h3>
                    <input class="inputText" type="text" name="mail" required="required">
                    <br>
                    <h3>Straße</h3>
                    <input class="inputText" type="text" name="street" required="required">
                    <br>
                    <h3>Postleitzahl</h3>
                    <input class="inputText" type="text" name="postal" required="required">
                    <br>
                    <h3>Stadt</h3>
                    <input class="inputText" type="text" name="city" required="required">
                    <br>
                    <h3>Telefonnummer</h3>
                    <input class="inputText" type="number" name="phone" required="required">
                    <br>
                </div>
                <div class="contentRight">
                    <h4>Ihre Nachricht</h4>
                    <br>
                    <h3>Betreff</h3>
                    <input class="inputTextRight" type="text" name="subject" required="required">
                    <br>
                    <h3>Buchungscode</h3>
                    <input class="inputTextRight" type="text" name="bookingCode" required="required">
                    <br>
                    <br><
                    <textarea></textarea>
                </div>
                <br>
                <button class="button" type="submit" name="submit">Absenden</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

**PHP**

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $firstName = $_POST['firstname'];
    $lastName = $_POST['lastname'];
    $mail = $_POST['mail'];
    $street = $_POST['street'];
    $postal = $_POST['postal'];
    $city = $_POST['city'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $subject = $_POST["subject"];
    $bookingCode = $_POST['bookingCode'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $data=$_POST["firstName"] ."\n".$_POST["firstName"] ."\n".$_POST["lastName"] ."\n".$_POST["mail"] ."\n".$_POST["street"] ."\n". $_POST["postal"] ."\n".$_POST["city"] ."\n".$_POST["phone"] ."\n". $_POST["subject"] ."\n".$_POST["bookingCode"] ."\n". $_POST["message"];
    $fp = fopen("data.txt", "a");
    fwrite($fp, $data);
    fclose($fp);
    header ("Location: NewTest.html?mailsent");
}
?>
```

Comment: Do you have an actual `form` element around the HTML snippet you have shown …? Please show the full form.

Comment: You're missing a `<form>`, so the page has nothing to "submit".

Comment: I edited it, doesnt' seem to work

Comment: @II337: Define "doesn't seem to work".  What specifically is happening and how does it fail?  Check your browser's debugging tools.  Is the POST request made?  Is it made to the URL you expect?  Does it contain the values you expect?  What is the server's response?

Answer (score 0):

You added action of form in div, move that from div to form.

```
<form action="contact-form.php" method="post">
    <div class="contact-form">
        <div class="contentLeft">
            <h4>Ihre Daten</h4>
            <br>
            <h3>Vorname</h3>
            <input class="inputText" type="text" name="firstName" required="required">
            <br>
            <h3>Nachname</h3>
            <input class="inputText" type="text" name="lastName" required="required">
            <br>
            <h3>E-Mail</h3>
            <input class="inputText" type="text" name="mail" required="required">
            <br>
            <h3>Straße</h3>
            <input class="inputText" type="text" name="street" required="required">
            <br>
            <h3>Postleitzahl</h3>
            <input class="inputText" type="text" name="postal" required="required">
            <br>
            <h3>Stadt</h3>
            <input class="inputText" type="text" name="city" required="required">
            <br>
            <h3>Telefonnummer</h3>
            <input class="inputText" type="number" name="phone" required="required">
            <br>
        </div>
        <div class="contentRight">
            <h4>Ihre Nachricht</h4>
            <br>
            <h3>Betreff</h3>
            <input class="inputTextRight" type="text" name="subject" required="required">
            <br>
            <h3>Buchungscode</h3>
            <input class="inputTextRight" type="text" name="bookingCode" required="required">
            <br>
            <br><
            <textarea></textarea>
        </div>
        <br>
        <button class="button" type="submit" name="submit">Absenden</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: That seems to work I get a 502 Bad Gateway though :(

Comment: It is working, then I believe error should be in contact-form.php file and make sure your server is running properly.